# Faster Algorithm for counting non-negative tripple(a, b, c) satisfied (a + b + c <= S) and (a * b * c <= T) and subproblem divisor summatory function

Tags: combinatorics, algorithms, harmonic-functions

#### Statement

[This problem](https://codeforces.com/blog/entry/93981)

[Code](https://ideone.com/yMi8tu)

Used this [Paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1206.3369.pdf)

---

---

---

Given $S, T (0 \leq S, T \leq 10^{18})$

I need to count the number of tuple $(a, b, c)$ satisfied $(\min(a, b, c) \geq 0)$ and $(a + b + c \leq S)$ and $(a \times b \times c \leq T)$

---

---

---

#### Combinatorics Approach

I tried to fix $a$ to be the minimum $\Rightarrow (0 \leq a \leq \sqrt[3]{T})$ then count the number of pair $(b, c)$ satisfied $(\min(b, c) \geq a)$ and $(b + c \leq S - a)$ and $(b \times c \leq \lfloor \frac{T}{a} \rfloor)$.

Because some tuple $(a, b, c)$ may equal to $(a, c, b), (b, a, c), (b, c, a), (c, a, b)$ or $(c, b, a)$ (example $a = b$), while some may not (example $a < b < c$). Therefore I split into 4 cases

> Case **[1]** $\Rightarrow$ $0 \leq a < b < c$ and $(a \leq \sqrt[3]{T})$

$cnt_1 = \overset{0}{\underset{a = 0}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{S}{\underset{b = 1}{\LARGE\sum}}\overset{S - b}{\underset{c = b + 1}{\LARGE\sum}} I(1) + \overset{\min(S, \lfloor \sqrt[3]{T} \rfloor)}{\underset{a = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{\min(S - a, \lfloor \frac{T}{a} \rfloor)}{\underset{b = a + 1}{\LARGE\sum}}\overset{\min(S - a - b, \lfloor \frac{T}{ab} \rfloor)}{\underset{c = b + 1}{\LARGE\sum}} I(1)$

$= \overset{S}{\underset{b = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \max(0, S - 2b) + \overset{\min(S, \lfloor \sqrt[3]{T} \rfloor)}{\underset{a = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{\min(S - a, \frac{T}{a})}{\underset{b = a + 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \max(0, \min(S - a - b, \lfloor \frac{T}{ab} \rfloor) - b)$

$ = \lfloor \frac{S}{2} \rfloor \times S - 2 \times \overset{\lfloor \frac{S}{2} \rfloor}{\underset{x = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} I(x) + \overset{\min(S, \lfloor \sqrt[3]{T} \rfloor) }{\underset{a = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \Huge($ $\overset{ f(a) }{\underset{x = 1}{\LARGE{\sum}}} \large{I(x)} + (S - a)(g(a) - a) - \overset{g(a)}{\underset{x = a + 1}{\LARGE\sum}} I(x) + \overset{f(a)}{\underset{x = g(a) + 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \lfloor \frac{T}{xa} \rfloor $$\Huge)$

for $I(x) = x$

for $f(a) = \Big\lfloor \min\Big(\frac{S - a}{2} \, \frac{T}{2a} + 1, \sqrt{\lfloor \frac{T}{a} \rfloor} \Big) \Big\rfloor$

and $g(a) = \max\Large(\normalsize k\ |\ S - a - k \leq \lfloor \frac{T}{a} \rfloor\Big)$

> Case **[2]** $\Rightarrow$ $0 \leq a < b = c$ and $(a \leq \sqrt[3]{T})$

$cnt_2 = \overset{0}{\underset{a = 0}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{\lfloor \frac{S}{2} \rfloor}{\underset{b = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{b}{\underset{c = b}{\LARGE\sum}} I(1) + \overset{\min(S, \lfloor \sqrt[3]{T} \rfloor)}{\underset{a = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{\min(\frac{S - a}{2}, \sqrt{\lfloor \frac{T}{a} \rfloor})}{\underset{b = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{b}{\underset{c = b}{\LARGE\sum}} I(1)$

$= \lfloor \frac{S}{2} \rfloor + \overset{min(S, \lfloor \sqrt[3]{T} \rfloor)}{\underset{a = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} max\Large( \normalsize 0, \Large \lfloor \normalsize min\Large(\normalsize \frac{S - a}{2}, \sqrt{\lfloor \frac{T}{a} \rfloor} \Large) \rfloor \normalsize - a \Large)$

> Case **[3]** $\Rightarrow$ $0 \leq a = b < c$ and $(a \leq \sqrt[3]{T})$

$cnt_3 = \overset{0}{\underset{a = 0}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{a}{\underset{b = a}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{S}{\underset{c = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} I(1) + \overset{\min(\lfloor \frac{S}{2} \rfloor, \lfloor \sqrt[3]{T} \rfloor)}{\underset{a = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{a}{\underset{b = a}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{\min(S - a - b, \lfloor \frac{T}{ab} \rfloor)}{\underset{c = b + 1}{\LARGE\sum}} I(1)$

$ = S + \overset{\min(\lfloor \frac{S}{2} \rfloor, \lfloor \sqrt[3]{T} \rfloor)}{\underset{a = 1}{\LARGE\sum}} \max\Large(\normalsize 0, min\Large(\normalsize S - 2a, \Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{T}{a^2} \Large \rfloor \Large)\normalsize - a\Large)$

> Case **[4]** $\Rightarrow$ $0 \leq a = b = c$ and $(a \leq \sqrt[3]{T})$

$cnt_4 = \overset{min(\frac{S}{3}, \sqrt[3]{T})}{\underset{a = 0}{\LARGE\sum}} \overset{a}{\underset{b = a}{\LARGE\sum}}\overset{b}{\underset{c = b}{\LARGE\sum}} I(1)$

$ = \lfloor \min(\frac{S}{3}, \sqrt[3]{T}) \rfloor + 1$

> Now *result* = number of different tuple $(a, b, c)$ satisfied the condition

In case **[1]** $(a, b, c) \neq (a, c, b) \neq (b, a, c) \neq (b, c, a) \neq (c, a, b) \neq (c, b, a)$

In case **[2]** $(a, b, c) \neq (b, c, a) \neq (c, a, b)$

In case **[3]** $(a, b, c) \neq (b, c, a) \neq (c, a, b)$

In case **[4]** $(a, b, c)$ is unique

Therefore, $result = 6 \times cnt_1 + 3 \times cnt_2 + 3 \times cnt_3 + 1 \times cnt_4$

---

---

---

#### Algorithm Complexity

It is known that $\overset{r}{\underset{x = l}{\Large\Sigma}} \normalsize (x) = \frac{r(r+1)}{2} - \frac{l(l-1)}{2}$ when $l \leq r$ and $\overset{r}{\underset{x = l}{\Large\Sigma}} \normalsize (x) = 0$ otherwise. Therefore this only take $O(1)$ complexity

Let $f(p, q, x) = \overset{min(q, \lfloor \frac{T}{x} \rfloor)}{\underset{k = 1}{\Sigma}} \lfloor \frac{T}{xk} \rfloor$

> There is $O(\sqrt{T})$ solution based on the fact that the number of different floor value in that series is $O(\sqrt{T})$

> There is also a $O(\sqrt[3]{T} log(T))$ solution based on the fact that the number of different slopes in from the graph of that series is $O(\sqrt[3]{T})$

The overall complexity should be $O\Big(\normalsize \overset{min(S, \lfloor \sqrt[3]{T} \rfloor)}{\underset{a = 1}{\Huge \Sigma}} \LARGE \sqrt[3]{\Large \lfloor \normalsize \sqrt[2]{\Large \lfloor \normalsize \frac{T}{a}} \Large \rfloor} \Large \rfloor \Large)  \Big)$

I expected the to be $O(\sqrt{T})$ or even be $O(\sqrt[3]{T})$ as it would in theory

But it seems to be about $O(T^{\frac{2}{3}})$ since I used many divisions and the correct solution (removed approximation part) for slope trick is not $O(T^{\frac{1}{3}})$ but much slower in theory (but still faster then all of my old correct-codes because it is division free as paper said)

---

---

---

#### UPDATE

My real complexity is only  $O\Huge(\normalsize \overset{min(S, \lfloor \sqrt[3]{T} \rfloor)}{\underset{a = 1}{\Huge \Sigma}} \LARGE( \normalsize log_2(\Large \lfloor \normalsize \sqrt{\frac{T}{a}} \Large \rfloor) \LARGE + \Large \lfloor \normalsize \normalsize \frac{T}{a} \Large \rfloor \LARGE ^{^{\normalsize 1/3}}) \Huge) \normalsize = O\Large( \int_{_{\normalsize 1}}^{^{\normalsize T^{1/3}}}\frac{\normalsize  T^{1/3}}{\normalsize  a^{1/3}} \normalsize da \Large) \normalsize = O(T^{5/9})$. Though I calculate upto $\Large \lfloor \normalsize min \Large( \normalsize (S - a) / 2, \sqrt{\frac{T}{a}} \Large) \rfloor$ only, but the number of unique value is still based on $\lfloor \frac{T}{a} \rfloor$. Therefore make my mistake

I also just remove the $\sqrt[3]{T}$ multiplying part as my mistake while writing latex.

I also used derivatives to give closer bound

---

---

---

#### Other known property

It is easy to known that by not fixing $a$ as minimum, you can also achieve $O(S \times \sqrt[3]{T})$.

By not depending on $O(f(t))$ factor, the complexity is $O(S^2)$ but might be possible to improve

There is special case when $S \leq \sqrt[3]{T}$ then we have $0 \leq a + b + c \leq S \leq \sqrt[3]{T} \leq T$. Therefore we get rid of the product-limitation condition part and the answer will be $\frac{(S+1)(S+2)(S+3)}{6}$

When $S = T = n$, the number of solution is approximately $1.5n^2$ Tested with 10.000.000 numbers $n \leq 10^9$ using this [algorithm](https://ideone.com/mmoWxJ)

---

---

---

#### My Question:

- Is there a way to run with smaller $a$ but not to increase the counting (b, c) part's complexity
- Is there a good formula to calculate $f(p, q, x)$ from $f(p, q, x - 1)$ or even from $f(l, r, x - 1)$ for some $(l, r)$

> Any of these questions below if it is solvable then the whole problem is solvable for $O(\sqrt[3]{T})$ !

- Is there an alternative formula which can run in $O(\sqrt[2](T))$ or even $O(\sqrt[3](T))$ ?
- Is there a faster algorithm to calculate $f(p, q, x)$ ?
- Can I calculate $f(p, q, x)$ from $f(l, r, x - 1)$ for some $(l, r)$ faster than $O(log(T))$ ?
- Given a array $p[]$ of $T$ numbers where $p[i] = \lfloor \frac{T}{i} \rfloor$. Given $O(\sqrt[3]{T})$ queries $Q(l, r, x) = \overset{r}{\underset{x = l}{\Sigma}} p[x]$. Can this be solved in $O(\sqrt[3]{T})$ after somehow compressing p[] and optimizing the calculation ?

Comment: These may help you : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4000405/find-the-number-of-possible-positive-integer-solutions-when-the-inequality-is-a , https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3488958/how-many-ordered-quadruples-of-positive-integers-a-b-c-d-are-there-such-th

Comment: Combine both things at the same times, I still find it very hard to solve

Comment: Also posted to (but closed on) MO, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/402275/faster-algorithm-for-counting-non-negative-triple-a-b-c-satisfied-a-b without notice to either site. That's an abuse.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought 2 sites are about different subject :(

Comment: If the sites are about different subjects, then the question must be off-topic at (at least) one of them. So, why did you post your question to a site where it would be off-topic?

Comment: Though it is the fact that my lack of sleeping, stupidness, carelessness cant be such a justification. I thought that by discussing to multiple sites on different subjects my improve the research if there is some cases matched. Yet it is a terrible mistake and I will not let my emotion of happy researching math make any mistakes like this in the future.

Comment: Posting the same question to multiple SE sites without notice is at best a minor transgression, especially considering OP might not have known about the site's policies regarding cross posting. Gerry, I think you're being a bit unnecessarily hostile here.